# LibGdx tilting an image

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm trying to create a children's game using the LibGdx framework. What I want to accomplish is to tilt an image of a balloon that will be used to collect points. So far I have added code to move the balloon up/down. I'm unable to figure out how to tilt it to the right or left.  Here is the code I have so far. Can someone please help

```
public class balloongame extends ApplicationAdapter {
SpriteBatch batch;
Texture background;
Texture balloon;
private float renderX;


@Override
public void create () {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    background = new Texture("bg.png");
    balloon = new Texture("final.png");
    renderX = 100;

}

@Override
public void render () {

    renderX += Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX();

    if(renderX < 0) renderX = 0;
    if(renderX > Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - 200) renderX = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - 200;

    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(background, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    batch.draw(balloon,renderX, Gdx.graphics.getWidth());
    batch.end();
}

@Override
public void dispose () {
    batch.dispose();

}
```

}

Comment: Take a look into [LibGDX Scene](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d). But you'd better start with [OpenGL RedBook](http://www.opengl-redbook.com/) in order to understand what the Scene is, and how it is generally working. LibGDX is an facade engine on top of OpenGL, with many helpful features.

Comment: I don't recommend using LibGDX Scene2d for most types of games. It complicates most types of games rather than helping. But it is very useful for the UI. You don't really need to know OpenGL to get started with LibGDX as it abstracts almost all of it away for new users. Over time you'll want to learn it so you'll understand optimization and how to do more complicated effects.

Comment: To tilt your balloon, use one of the `batch.draw` methods that has a rotation parameter.

Comment: @Tenfour04 rotation is not tilt.

Comment: ??? @DenizYılmaz If you rotate something, it is tilted.

Comment: @Tenfour04 tilt usually using for shear in photoshop instead of rotation ,more likely giving some perspective to it.

Comment: If Photoshop uses the word tilt to describe shear, it's a poor choice of words because it doesn't match the dictionary definition. If describing tilt in about an axis other than Z, then it would be about perspective, but I think OP is asking for rotation about Z because a balloon is round so it looks the same from any angle in 3D. But I guess they could be going for a Paper Mario art style.

Comment: You may be right. Actually community uses this word not ps. I will be sad if op really asking about rotation since i wrote detailed answer :(.

Answer (score 0):

I know two easy ways to do it.

Affine2 class have shear method in it.And similar transformation methods.

[Affine2.shear()](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Affine2.html#shear-float-float-)

After you set affine matrix you can draw it with

[draw(TextureRegion region, float width, float height, Affine2 transform)](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Batch.html#draw-com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion-float-float-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Affine2-)

---

I prefer changing vertices attributes in draw method.

[draw(Texture texture,
          float[] spriteVertices,
          int offset,
          int count)](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Batch.html#draw-com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture-float:A-int-int-)

There must be 4 vertices, each made up of 5 elements in this order: x, y, color, u, v

```
batch.draw(textures[0], new float[]{
                        0, 0 ,Color.RED.toFloatBits(), 0f, 1f,
                        textures[0].getWidth(),50, Color.BLUE.toFloatBits(), 1f, 1f,
                        textures[0].getWidth(), 50+textures[1].getHeight(), Color.GREEN.toFloatBits(), 1f, 0f,
                        0 ,textures[0].getHeight(), Color.GOLD.toFloatBits(), 0f, 0f},0,20);
```

You can set individial colors for each vertice or simply can set color to white.

[image: example1]

You can change it however you want.

[image]